# How to Loop through JAXB classes, if there are more than one level of same XML node

Tags: java, jaxb

This is the prettiest version of my actual XML (I do not have an XSD for it, and will not have it from source system)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <!--Java Class Comp.java-->
  <Comp>
    <Name>Component Name</Name>
    <Available_Start_Date>2018-07-10</Available_Start_Date>
 <!--Java Class P_to_P.java-->
    <P_to_P>
      <Max>1</Max>
      <Min>1</Min>
   <!-- Java Class P.java-->
      <P>
        <Name>Composite</Name>
        <P_to_P>
          <Max>1</Max>
          <Min>1</Min>
          <P>
            <Name>Another Level</Name>
          </P>
        </P_to_P>
        <P_to_P>
          <Max>1</Max>
          <Min>1</Min>
          <P>
            <Name>Yet Another Level</Name>
          </P>
        </P_to_P>
      </P>
    </P_to_P>
  </Comp>
</Root>
```

Now, if I start writing JAXB classes for it (By Hand and using IDE) I have to write for loop for every level I am going through. Now, the child in this XML might appear as Parent of the child (P_to_P has P as a child and P has P_to_P as child, and the depth of the parent-child relation can be of any number of level's.

So, if I write a Main JAXB file, then would I have to write those many number of for loops inside a for loop to iterate through all Parents and Child? or is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: You need to write only 4 Java classes: `Root`, `Comp`, `P_to_P` and `P`. Class `P_to_P` would contain a `P` property. And class `P` would contain a `List<P_to_P>` property. The recursion does not raise any additional difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I partially followed it. Till creating 4 classes and referencing I am good. What I am not sure is, when I write my Main class, in Main class I don't know how many levels of P_to_P and P are there. So, right now I am writing for loop inside for loop for every level but at runtime how do I know how many for loops in a for loop I need

Comment: So your problem is not about JAXB unmarshalling, but with the processing after that? You need to iterate through your `P_to_P` and `P`instances with recursion.. You should edit your question and add your for-loop attempt to get better help.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize the question was focussed on creating those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your POJO classes `P` and `P_to_P` similar to this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class P_to_P {

    @XmlElement(name = "Max")
    private int max;

    @XmlElement(name = "Min")
    private int min;

    @XmlElement(name = "P")
    private P p;

    // public getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class P {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "P_to_P")
    private List<P_to_P> pToPList;

    // public getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}
```

Then can you walk through the whole tree and process every item like below.
Notice the recursion: Method `process(P_to_P)` calls `process(P)`,
and method `process(P)` calls `process(P_to_P)`.
Notice also the checks for `null` to prevent `NullPointerException` and terminate the recursion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("root.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCntext.createUnmarshaller();
    Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    P_to_P pToP = root.getComp().getPToP();
    process(pToP);
}

private static void process(P_to_P pToP) {
   if (pToP == null)
       return;

   // do anything you like here

   process(pToP.getP());
}

private static void process(P p) {
   if (p == null)
       return;

   // do anything you like here

   if (p.getpToPList() == null)
       return;
   for (P_to_P pToP : p.getpToPList()) {
       process(pToP);
   }
}
```